# Appropriate way to batch method invocations?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Suppose something like the following:

```
public boolean doThisThing(SomeArg arg) {
    if(iAmAllowedToDoIt()) {
        doThing(arg);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Suppose that iAmAllowedToDoIt() is a very expensive method, and doThisThing() is invoked by many threads concurrently, and I am allowed to do everything given that I am allowed to do anything, is there a way to batch invocations of iAmAllowedToDoIt() such that I would accumulate SomeArgs in a concurrent data structure, and invoke doThing on all of them at once after resolving iAmAllowedToDoIt only one time **without modifying the API**? What would that code look like? I can't figure out how to do multithreaded batching performantly like this **without modifying the API**. An ideal answer would include something that doesn't rely on blocking for a fixed period of time to accumulate invocations of doThisThing().

Ideally it would end up as something like:

1. Call doThisThing
2. Call iAmAllowedToDoIt asynchronously
3. All calls to doThisThing before (2) retuns block until (2) returns
4. (2) Returns, if true invoke doThing for all blocked doThisThing()s

Comment: You mean like caching the result of `iAmAllowedToDoIt()`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, caching the result is insufficient, as the cache would have to be invalidated at some unknown time in the future when iAmAllowedToDoIt() would return false, which cannot be determined without calling it.

Comment: Please don't try to put multiline information or code in the comments. Add it to the question.

Comment: When can the allow method return false again after having returned true once?

Comment: it can return false or true at any time, merely that all calls to doThisThing() that occur during a given invocation of iAmAllowedToDoIt() share the result of iAmAllowedToDoIt()

Comment: @user3015990: then, the prerequisites of your question are inconsistent. Without knowing how long or under which conditions a result remains valid, even sharing the result of an ongoing evaluation is effectively an inappropriate caching. Keep in mind that there is no guaranty about how long it takes between the completion of `iAmAllowedToDoIt()` by one thread and the awakening of another waiting thread. Besides that, what if `iAmAllowedToDoIt()` wants to allow a certain number of callers (i.e. threads) to proceed? There’s too little information about the acceptance rules…

Answer (score 0):

Your containing object could have an [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) that holds a [CompleteableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) for the computation of `iAmAllowedToDoIt()`. Additional invocations of `doThisThing()` simply await the completion of the completable future if one is present or create a new one otherwise, with an appropriate CAS loop to avoid creating more than one instance at a time.

Upon completion the reference is set to null again so that threads invoking the method at a later point can start a new computation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following (which implements an algorithm similar to the one proposed by @the8472) :

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * Lock used to guard accesses to allowedFuture
     */
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    /**
     * The future result being computed, reset to null as soon as the result is known
     */
    private FutureTask<Boolean> allowedFuture = null;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public boolean doThisThing() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        if (iAmAllowedToDoIt()) {
            System.out.println("doing it...");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not doing it...");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean iAmAllowedToDoIt() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        // if true, this means that this thread is the one which must really compute if I am allowed
        boolean mustCompute = false;

        // The Future holding the result which is either the cached one, or a new one stored in the cache
        FutureTask<Boolean> result;

        synchronized (lock) {
            // if no one has computed the result yet, or if it has been computed and thus must be recomputed
            // then create it
            if (this.allowedFuture == null) {
                mustCompute = true;
                this.allowedFuture = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("computing if I am allowed...");
                        Thread.sleep(RANDOM.nextInt(3000));
                        boolean allowed = RANDOM.nextBoolean();
                        System.out.println(allowed ? "allowed!" : "not allowed!");
                        return allowed;
                    }
                });
            }
            result = this.allowedFuture;
        }
        if (mustCompute) {
            allowedFuture.run();

            // reset the cache to null, so that the next thread recomputes the result
            synchronized (lock) {
                this.allowedFuture = null;
            }
        }
        return result.get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(RANDOM.nextInt(6000));
                    test.doThisThing();
                }
                catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah makes perfect sense, I didn't know about future tasks before.

Comment: there's a race condition that doesn't affect correctness on setting mustCompute, though - you could theoretically live lock on threads never entering the if(mustCompute) block to run the future, but it's unlikely. Thanks for this though! =)